# angular2 rc.5 custom input, No value accessor for form control with unspecified name

Tags: angular

I have simple custom input component like this,

```js
import {Component, Provider, forwardRef} from "@angular/core";
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";

const noop = () => {};

const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-input',
  template: `

          <input class="form-control" 
                 [(ngModel)]="value" name="somename"
                 (blur)="onTouched()">

  `,
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor{

  //The internal data model
  private _value: any = '';

  //Placeholders for the callbacks
  private _onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;

  private _onChangeCallback: (_:any) => void = noop;

  //get accessor
  get value(): any { return this._value; };

  //set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this._value) {
      this._value = v;
      this._onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  //Set touched on blur
  onTouched(){
    this._onTouchedCallback();
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this._value = value;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this._onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  //From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

}
```

and I have app module like this,

```js
/**
 * Created by amare on 8/15/16.
 */
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }                from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule }          from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }                 from './app/app.component';
import {CustomInputComponent} from "./app/shared/custom.input.component";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, RouterModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CustomInputComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {  
}
```

and main

```js
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and I have used my custom input in one of my components as shown below, but am getting 'No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute'.

```html
<custom-input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName"></custom-input>
```

and the app.component looks like this

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  firstName: string;
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue with a custom directive that implements ControlValueAccessor. It was working in RC4 but gets same error as you for RC5. Hoping someone has a solution.

Comment: Try adding `ngDefaultControl` to your control, like this:
`<custom-input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName" ngDefaultControl></custom-input>`

Comment: @danieleds thanks so much it works like a charm, even though the angular team was not responding.

Comment: Beware of any 3rd-party packages you may be using - if you import anything that is making use of the old `FORM_DIRECTIVES`, it will break your app!
Case in point: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/352

Comment: For me adding ngDefaultControl before [(ngModel)]="...." worked

Answer (score 74):

adding ngDefaultControl to the custom input component in the host solved the issue, thanks @danieleds

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I have a name applied to my `input` and i also tried adding `ngDefaultControl` to the input and it did not work. Still gave me the same error. In RC5

Comment: Agree, I added name property in html and ngDefaultControl and I use formControl and it does not work.

Comment: See a very good explanation on how `ngDefaultControl` works - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465959/968003. Essentially, it adds default `ControlValueAccessor`, which acts as a bridge between the Angular forms API and a native element in the DOM.

Answer (score 46):

Add ngDefaultControl to the custom-input component. This adds two-way databinding, you shouldn't have to implement the value accessor methods unless you are doing something unique.

```
<custom-input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName" ngDefaultControl></custom-input>
```

Answer (score 13):

Add `ngDefaultControl` to your input. eg

```
<inline-editor type="textarea" [(ngModel)]="editableTextArea" (onSave)="saveEditable($event)" value="valor" ngDefaultControl> </inline-editor>
```

Then `import { FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common'`;

Finally directives: `[FORM_DIRECTIVES]`

This will work :) Thanks for the above comments

Comment: Please use backticks and other `markdown` commands to make your post more readable.

Comment: I am using RC6 and there isn't `FORM_DIRECTIVES` in `@angular/common`

Comment: FORM DIRECTIVES ARE NO MORE WITH NG2 FINAL

Answer (score 4):

I was putting `[(ngModel)]` on my `<option>` tag instead of `<select>`

So yeah... that will cause this.

Comment: Yup....  I had the same error, putting the ngModel on a <mat-radio-button>, rather than the <mat-radio-group>.   Grrrrrr....

Answer (score 0):

As yet another scenario where this comes up, I had `[(ngModel)]` specified on a custom component which was recently rebuilt and simplified, and the new version of the component just had `ngModel` as a normal input variable with emits.

*This was not enough* - the input variable must be renamed to something besides `ngModel`, or the component must implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface ([see the docs for details](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)).  Once one or the other is complete, you will no longer get this error.