# No value accessor for form control with name: 'recipient'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I got this error after upgrading to Angular 2 Rc.5.
This is my component template:

```
<md-input
    [(ngModel)]="recipient"
    name="recipient"
    placeholder="Name"
    class="col-sm-4"
    (blur)="addRecipient(recipient)">
</md-input>
```

My app.module.ts imports the `FormsModule`

I also tried to declare `private recipient;` in my component.

Am I missing something? Why do I get this error?

```
No value accessor for form control with name: 'recipient'
```

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958347/angular2-rc-5-custom-input-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified/39013152#39013152 ?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You should add the ngDefaultControl attribute to your input like this:

```
<md-input
    [(ngModel)]="recipient"
    name="recipient"
    placeholder="Name"
    class="col-sm-4"
    (blur)="addRecipient(recipient)"
    ngDefaultControl>
</md-input>
```

Taken from comments in this post:

[angular2 rc.5 custom input, No value accessor for form control with unspecified name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958347/angular2-rc-5-custom-input-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified)

**Note: For later versions of @angular/material:**

Nowadays you should instead write:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input
        mdInput
        [(ngModel)]="recipient"
        name="recipient"
        placeholder="Name"
        (blur)="addRecipient(recipient)">
</md-input-container>
```

See https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Comment: It works for me but can someone explain me why we have to add "ngDefaultControl" ?

Comment: That was because md-input was no known tag for ngModel, but for recent versions of @angular/material you should use the input tag with mdInput as an attribute instead wrapped in an md-input-container element. See https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you import MaterialModule as well since you are using md-input which does not belong to FormsModule

Comment: What npm package should be installed to get the MaterialModule?

Comment: I think it's @angular2-material/core

Comment: No MaterialModule in @angular2-material/core

Comment: ok I checked it and you need to do: 
npm install @angular2-material/core --save
and
npm install @angular2-material/input --save,

then import MdInputModule from @angular2-material/input

Comment: I have imported the MdInputModule, but when I add [(ngModel)] to my md-input I get the same error message as in the question: "No value accessor for form control". Have you tested with ngModel? (which is what the question referred to).

Comment: Yes I have and it worked for me... Are you sure you imported it to the right module?

Comment: Yes I did import the MdInputModule (I already had). But this happened for me just as posted in the question after upgrading to angular2 rc 5 (and also upgraded angular materials to alpha 7). But I made it work again by adding the ngDefaultControl attribute to the md-input tag. Also see the post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958347/angular2-rc-5-custom-input-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified