# What directives and other features are available for inputs with a ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a custom component. It has a `ControlValueAccessor` injected into it as a provider. This is the generic standard way to make custom components represent form inputs.

For a more precise example the component actually implements `ControlValueAccessor` and injects itself into itself. This detail should not be important.

I know that this makes the following things available for this component out of the box:

- `ngModel` directive for two-way data binding
- several css-classes managed by Angular: `ng-dirty`/`ng-pristine`, `ng-valid` and `ng-touched`

Is there any other directives available out of the box besides `ngModel`? I would expect at least something like blur and change events to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465891/what-is-ngdefaultcontrol-in-angular/46465959#46465959

Comment: If you will create a plunker i can show you which exact directives are applied to your element