# How to bind to model with Angular Material <mat-button-toggle>?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Take a look at this Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/yu95hUrKlUh4Ttc5SwYD?p=preview

When I'm using `<mat-slide-toggle>`, I am able to modify the values in my component:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="myFlagForSlideToggle">Toggle me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

`myFlagForSlideToggle` is updated as expected.

But when I'm using `<mat-button-toggle>`, the values are not updated. I had to add `ngDefaultControl` to even make this example work, but I'm not sure how it matters.

```
<mat-button-toggle [(ngModel)]="myFlagForButtonToggle" ngDefaultControl>Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>
```

What is the correct way to bind a button state to the component?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`MatButtonToggle` component doesn't implement `ControlValueAccessor` therefore you can't use `ngModel` on it. `ngDefaultControl` was introduced for [other purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465891/what-is-ngdefaultcontrol-in-angular/46465959#46465959).

`MatButtonToggle` is supposed to be a part of `mat-button-toggle-group`. But if you want to use it as a standalone component and bind model to it here is some example of how you can do it:

```html
<mat-button-toggle 
  [checked]="myFlagForButtonToggle" 
  (change)="myFlagForButtonToggle = $event.source.checked">
    Toggle me!
</mat-button-toggle>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/05MYXTiVAiWWk4mil5V2?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you! was trying to do things with observable on an object from parent component but didn´t get it working. This made the trick (BUT, was not working for the observable array, only a regular one..

Answer (score 27):

If you are trying to use `mat-button-toggle` to switch between enabling / disabling something, you will have to use a binding on `mat-button-toggle-group`, and make sure that the `mat-button-toggle`'s themselves have the boolean values of `true` and `false`, not the string values. That is to say:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [(ngModel)]="isEnabled">
    <mat-button-toggle [value]="true"> Enable </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle [value]="false"> Disable </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, because this works and is cleanest way to do it without click or change handlers.

Comment: @JanneHarju No, this is perfectly fine as a second answer.
It would result in 2 buttons - a.k.a. not what the question asked for.

And it cannot _easily_ be adapted to fit the requirement, either. A single button like `<mat-button-toggle [value]="true">Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>`  would not work.

Comment: Binding the value of the actual toggle buttons was the 'trick'

Answer (score 18):

`mat-button-toggle` dont have a boolean value and `[(ngModel)]` won't work. See [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview).

These toggles can be configured to behave as either radio-buttons or checkboxes.

a use case may be like this

```
<mat-button-toggle-group  [(ngModel)]="myFlagForButtonToggle">
  <mat-button-toggle value="button1"  ngDefaultControl>Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="button2"  ngDefaultControl>Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="button3"  ngDefaultControl>Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

and change your boolean to `myFlagForButtonToggle :string;`

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-button-toggle-group'

Comment: Everything works like it should... just import CommonModule for NgModel to work...

Comment: Brilliant. Other solutions work, but this is by far the easiest and most "normal" for data binding.

Comment: This should be the best answer, which is exactly the design and the feature mentioned in the official document. But `ngModel` lives in `FormModule`, which means that `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` is required to be imported into AppModule

Comment: This contains something good and something bad. Code itself works. It was good part. But that part where you say "toggle button won't work with boolean" is wrong. Check Andrew Favaloro answer above. surrounfing value with [] you can set boolean value. otherwise it is string. Maybe in 2017 situation was different.

Answer (score 6):

```
public selectedVal: string;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){
  this.selectedVal ='option1';
} 

public onValChange(val: string) {
  this.selectedVal = val;
}

 <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [value]="selectedVal" (change)="onValChange(group.value)" >
  <mat-button-toggle value="option1">
    Option 1
  </mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="option2">
    Option 2
  </mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Custom Form Control for the Angular Material Button Toggle Group. Here is how I implemented it:

**custom-button-toggle-group.component.html**

```
<mat-button-toggle-group
  (change)="onToggleGroupChange($event)"
  [disabled]=disabled
  [value]=value
>
  <mat-button-toggle
    *ngFor="let toggle of toggles"
    [value]="toggle.value"
  >{{ toggle.label }}</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**custom-button-toggle-group.component.ts**

```
import { Component, forwardRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonToggleChange } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';

export interface ButtonToggle {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-button-toggle-group',
  templateUrl: './button-toggle-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-toggle-group.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomButtonToggleGroupComponent),
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomButtonToggleGroupComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() public toggles: ButtonToggle[];

  public value: string;
  public disabled: boolean;

  private onChange: (value: string) => void;
  private onTouched: () => void;


  public onToggleGroupChange({ value }: MatButtonToggleChange): void {
    this.doChange(value);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  private doChange(selectedValue: string): void {
    this.onChange(selectedValue);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  private doBlur(): void {
    this.onTouched();
  }

}
```

This way you will be able to use `FormControl`, `FormControlName`, etc. on the `custom-button-toggle-group`.

Comment: Right the solution I though to implement, clear, simple and reusable. I've used  taken it, thank you

Comment: @JosilloDebian same thought exactly

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="flags" style="width: 100%" (change)="onChangeFlag($event)">
    <mat-button-toggle *ngFor="let flag of allFlags" value="{{flag.flag}}" style="width: 100%;" 
    matTooltip="{{flag.name}}" [checked]="flagSelected == flag.flag"
    > <img [alt]="flag" src="assets/images/flags/{{flag.flag}}.png" width="20px"/> 
    </mat-button-toggle>

  </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Angular Material. I provided name and id attributes along with ngModel attribute (for template driven forms) for  to bind to model values. It worked for me.

Please see code below:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" name="fontStyle" id="fontStyle">
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me.

My typescript:

```
myFlagForButtonToggle: boolean = false
```

My HTML:

```
   <mat-button-toggle 
      [checked]="myFlagForButtonToggle" 
      (change)="myFlagForButtonToggle = !myFlagForButtonToggle">
        Toggle me!
    </mat-button-toggle>
```