# Binding Mat-Button-Toggle v binding Mat-Slide-Toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

How come this works fine. I.E isPrint shows as true or false on clicking the slide toggle

```
<div>
 <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isPrint" #toggleSlide></mat-slide- 
 toggle>
isPrint: {{ isPrint }}
</div>
```

But this does not work and gives the error ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with an unspecified name attribute

```
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle [(ngModel)]="isPrint" #toggleBtn>Toggle</mat-button-toggle>
  isPrint: {{ isPrint }}
</div>
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind to model with Angular Material <mat-button-toggle>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083164/how-to-bind-to-model-with-angular-material-mat-button-toggle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-button-toggle-slider-toggle)

[**MatButtonToggle component doesn't implement ControlValueAccessor**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47083671/3937794), 
therefore, you can't use `[(ngModel)]` on it.

*MatButtonToggle is supposed to be a part of mat-button-toggle-group*.

But if you want to use it as a standalone component and bind model to it, you have to do something like below:~

```
<mat-button-toggle 
    [checked]="isPrint" 
    (change)="isPrint = $event.source.checked">
    Toggle
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm going to accept this but I need to research $event.source.checked as I haven't seen that before.