# No value accessor for form control with name: 'dateTime'

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am trying to apply external library for datetime picker. I am getting an error like below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'dateTimeDeparture'
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'dateTimeDeparture'
```

**My code is below:**

**Template:**

```
<owl-dateTime-input [(ngModel)]="flightDetails.dateTimeDeparture" name="dateTimeDeparture" [locale]="en" required></owl-dateTime-input>
```

**Component:**

```
this.en = {
    firstDayOfWeek: 0,
    dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
    monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]
};

this.flightDetails = {
    dateTimeDeparture: new Date(2017, 8, 10, 13, 30, 30),
    dateTimeArrival: new Date(2017, 8, 10, 13, 30, 30)
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

External library require a ControlValueAccessor to work with angular forms.

Try to add `ngDefaultControl` like this:

```
<owl-dateTime-input [(ngModel)]="flightDetails.dateTimeDeparture" name="dateTimeDeparture" [locale]="en" required formControlName="dateTimeDeparture" ngDefaultControl></owl-dateTime-input>
```

or

```
<owl-dateTime-input [(ngModel)]="flightDetails.dateTimeDeparture" name="dateTimeDeparture" [locale]="en" required ngDefaultControl></owl-dateTime-input>
```

Look here:

[What is ngDefaultControl in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465891/what-is-ngdefaultcontrol-in-angular)