# Angular2 to show string/key used in ngModel dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am new to angular2. I have been trying to find the possible ways to show the string which is used for binding in `[(ngModel)]` dynamically. My objective to show the binding key which is used in HTML Elements in DOM itself based on Url param. Since my application is huge this will be more productive for development.

I need to show every ngModel string/key which is placed under  any div wrapper using 'Directive'. Let say 'showModelKey' will be used to identify the elements placed under Div wrapper.

```
<div class='content-wrapper' showModelKey>
 <input [(ngModel)]="myFirstName" name="first_name">
  <!-- here myFirstName is ngModel string/key -->
....
 <textarea[(ngModel)]="commentModel" name="comment"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Here **showModelKey** should find the fields used under div wrapper and add another directive (if needed) to show the key  which is used for **ngModel** binding in **DOM**.

[image]

From above example screen, **myFirstName** is ngModel key has been shown in DOM.

Please advise the possible way to achieve this.

**Updated** : Is it possible to override the ngModel directive? If so, can we get the key before it get parsed?

Comment: If you are looking for a way to debug/inspect the bindings in your app [Augury](https://augury.angular.io/) is a helpful Chrome extension.

Comment: Perhaps if you use NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, you can intercept before override, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465959/3415716

Answer (score 3):

You could do that by creating a wrapper object, which would be responsible for holding `key` & `value` pair of all dynamic values. That object name could be `model` inside component.

```
//inside component
model: any = {};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='content-wrapper' showModelKey>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model[dynamicKey1]" name="first_name">
  <!-- here myFirstName is ngModel string/key -->
  ....
  <textarea[(ngModel)]="model[dynamicKey2]" name="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: since i could not update the existing ngModel key in whole application, i tried another approach based on directive. This directive should show ngModel key in DOM. Thanks again

Comment: @mymotherland don't understand you last statement, would you elaborate more on it?

Comment: Plz look on example screen. I need to show the ngModel key in DOM next to field used in component templates.

Comment: Is it possible to override the ngModel directive? If so, can we get the key before it get parsed?

Comment: Wow! A lifesaver. Thank you.