# Angular 8 - FormArray "No value accessor for form control with path"

Tags: angular, formarray, form-control, angular-ngselect

I'm using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) on a form, but now I want to wrap a specific configuration of this on a custom component. The problem is I'm using a `FormArray` which contains several of this, in the next way:

```
this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group(
  {
    ...
    linkedRoles: this.formBuilder.array([])
  }
);
```

This `linkedRoles` is populated with the next `FormGroup`:

```
let fgRoles: FormGroup;

for (let i = 0; i < this.userRoles.length; i++) {
  fgRoles = this.formBuilder.group({
    activeRole: [{ value: null }],
    roles: [{ value: null }]
  });
  this.linkedRoles.push(fgRoles);
  this.linkedRoles.controls[i].setValue({
    activeRole: this.userRoles[i].role,
    roles: this.extractUserRoles(this.userRoles[i])
  });
```

A getter is created for simplicity too:

```
get linkedRoles(): FormArray {
  return <FormArray>this.profileForm.get("linkedRoles");
}
```

After this, in my template, I was using this composition which was working perfectly:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm">
  ...

  <table>
    ...
    <tbody>
      <tr formArrayName="linkedRoles"
        *ngFor="let usuR of userRoles;
          let idx = index"
      >
        ...
        <td data-label="Roles" [formGroupName]="idx">
          <ng-select #rolesNgSelect
            [hideSelected]="false"
            bindLabel="rol"
            ...
            formControlName="roles"
          >

            <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
              ...
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
              ...
            </ng-template>

          </ng-select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</form>
```

Now, I'm trying to substitute the `ng-select` by my custom component `role-selector`, which basically receives all the necessary properties from the `ng-select` and wraps this in the template. The change in my previous template is as follows:

```
<tr formArrayName="linkedRoles"
  *ngFor="let usuR of userRoles;
    let idx = index;
    let ctrlRol of linkedRoles.controls"
>
  <td>
    <app-role-selector
      [hideSelected]="false"
      bindLabel="rol"
      ...
      formControlName="roles"
    >
    </app-role-selector>
  </td>
</tr>
```

With this subtle change, I'm receiving the next error in console:

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'linkedRoles -> 0 -> roles'
```

Strangest thing is, when I click the unstyled box that appears, it loads and works almost fine. Should I move my `formControlName` tag to the `ng-select` inside my component's template?

### **POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

Looking for a solution, [I found the interesting `ngDefaultControl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465891/what-is-ngdefaultcontrol-in-angular/46465959). Adding this directive to my custom component makes it behave as expected. Now it looks like this:

```
<app-role-selector
  [hideSelected]="false"
  bindLabel="rol"
  ...
  ngDefaultControl
  formControlName="roles"
>
```

The only counterside is I don't fully understand why this is necessary and if this is the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is not the OP's problem but if it helps anyone, I received a similar error, with my setup. I'm in Angular 13, using Angular Material, and a FormArray. Where a form control in my array uses a [mat-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview).

Simple fix, I forgot to import the 'MatCheckboxModule' into my module. And now no more errors. Definitely misleading for me, as I thought it was a form issue, not a missing module. Hope that helps anyone

Comment: you were sent from heaven. I was moving stuff to different module that uses ngrx store (which i am not very familiar with) and i was searching the whole store / observable code for my mistake, when the other module just didn't have the checkbox imported.

Comment: @Woozar glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 5):

The error says `No value accessor for form control with path: 'linkedRoles -> 0 -> roles'`.

To solve this, begin by finding The control with the name `roles`. This is `ng-select`. But we know that `ng-select` has a `ValueAccessor`... So why would angular complain?

The reason is basically that you have not imported `NgSelectModule` in the module where you have declared your component.

**But why doesn't Angular complain about unknown element?** See this link [Ivy is not complaining about unknown element inside ng-template #36171](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36171). Angular will not complain about the unkown element but will complain about `ValueAccessor`

Comment: I pretty much understand what you're saying, Owen, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. My `roles` controls is now defined in my custom component, `app-role-selector`, instead of in my `ng-select`. 

As a curiosity, searching for a solution, I found `ngDefaultControl` directive, which looks like is working as I expected.

Comment: Can you share the module on which you have declared your component?

Comment: Thank you for saying HOW to figure out the issue.  Was facing this in a unit test and it was already complicated enough getting the ViewChild reference to not be undefined.  Found this...10 seconds after reading this, unit test completed!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are having `ng-select` related template inside `app-role-selector`.

### Parent.component.html

```
// *ngFor="let role of linkedRoles"

<app-role-selector
      [hideSelected]="false"
      bindLabel="rol"
      ...
      [parentFormArray]='role'>
</app-role-selector>
```

### role-selector.component.ts

```
 export class RoleSelector {

    @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
}
```

### role-selector.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm"> // ----> this will have the ref of fgRoles (formGroup) 
     <ng-select #rolesNgSelect
            [hideSelected]="false"
            bindLabel="rol"
            ...
            formControlName="roles"> ----> fgRoles.get('roles')
      ...
     </ng-select>
</form>
```

Now let's understand the below error

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'linkedRoles -> 0 -> roles'
```

When we add `formControlName` in `<app-role-selector>`, it means we are telling angular to treat `<app-role-selector>` as any other input field. But as then we have to configure the component to act like a input element (i.e. store value and interact with form element).

[More details about Custom Value Accessor](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-a0ed4ad0fafd)

Comment: Thanks for your resposne, Lalit. I understand now what you're doing, actually I tried to do something similar (with no success). The problem is my component is part of a much bigger form with other fields, and I'm trying to respect that structure. Looking for a solution I found the interesting `ngDefaultControl` directive, which do the trick and make my component work as expected.